# How to achieve Google Play Newsstand Page Tab UI?

Tags: android, user-interface, user-experience

### What I want to achieve?

I recorded a video of the Tab transition animation.

- Video: `https://www.dropbox.com/s/h8k5uy3z5gwbzoc/File%206-24-15%2C%2019%2015%2012.mov?dl=0`

There are several flows I would like to describe below:

- Centering the selected item in normal (**I did this**)
- Transit the tab container when user scroll it up to the top. I thought it was a padding animation but it doesn't seem to the right way.
- Transit the tab container back when user scroll it down.
- Change the transparency along with the scroll. (**I can almost do this by catching the scrolling event**)

### What I have tried?

- I use this `https://github.com/jpardogo/PagerSlidingTabStrip` to achieve the center position of selected tab.
- I'm using padding to transit the tab container but I think it's not the right way.
- Still no code here, but I'll post it if it's helpful.

Please help!

Answer (score 3):

Try new [google design support library](https://medium.com/ribot-labs/exploring-the-new-android-design-support-library-b7cda56d2c32) and go through the AppBar and it's layout_scrollFlags options for various mode.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/florent37/MaterialViewPager

https://github.com/naman14/PlayNewsStandDemo

This guys made the exact mock of GooglePlayNewStand.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I read all of them and there are some points I didn't love from their implementation. On the other hand, the most difficult part which I want to create is the transition of the Tab layout when user scrolls up an down. For example the transparency changes (it's easy), end the position changes too (current tab at the middle of the screen, but it change to the left when you scroll up, and there is a transition animation between).

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.